Spring Boot / Spring Security - CSRF token always Invalid
My CSRF token on a Spring Auth Server has a custom cookie name.
But whenever I submit a form login, the server doesn't validate the CSRF token.
I get this error:

But in my security chain I only have this:
// enable csrf
    http.csrf { csrf ->
        csrf.csrfTokenRepository(customServletCsrfTokenRepository)
        csrf.sessionAuthenticationStrategy(customCsrfAuthenticationStrategy)
        csrf.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher { request ->
            !request.method.equals("GET", ignoreCase = true)
        }
    }

The implementation of the repository is as below (so I'm not changing much) - I'm using the default cookietokenrepository:
@Repository
internal class CustomServletCsrfTokenRepository : CsrfTokenRepository {

    companion object {
        private const val CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-AUTH-TOKEN"
        private const val CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-AUTH-TOKEN"
        private const val CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME = "_csrf"
        private const val COOKIE_PATH = "/"
        private const val COOKIE_SAME_SITE = "Strict"
    }
    private val cookieCsrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository()

    init {
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieName(CSRF_COOKIE_NAME)
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setHeaderName(CSRF_HEADER_NAME)
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setParameterName(CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME)
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieCustomizer { cookie ->
            cookie.httpOnly(true)
            cookie.secure(false) // scope is not just on secure connections
            cookie.sameSite(COOKIE_SAME_SITE)
            cookie.maxAge(-1)
            cookie.path(COOKIE_PATH)
        }
    }

    override fun generateToken(request: HttpServletRequest): CsrfToken {
        return cookieCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(request)
    }

    override fun saveToken(
        token: CsrfToken?,
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse?
    ) {
        println("Saving CSRF Token: ${token?.token}")
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(token, request, response)
    }

    override fun loadToken(request: HttpServletRequest): CsrfToken? {
        println("Loaded CSRF Token: ${cookieCsrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request)?.token}")
        return cookieCsrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request)
    }
}

I have a two print lines, the load token, and the save token. The load token though shows null, but it's definitely there as a request cookie, if you see here (on the POST/login request):

Because it fails, no session is created and it redirects to session-expired (which hasn't been implemented yet), so it redirects back to the login page.
Can anyone help?

if you are using the default  cookie token repository then why does your code reference some customServletCsrfTokenRepository? Why not just set it with .csrf((csrf) -> csrf .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())); which is also the way the documentation shows it?

Hi J, I extended the csrf repository to accommodate for the different name, but maybe I haven’t extended it in the right way. I’ll upload my auth server code to a repo and get back to you. There is no angular interaction yet, this was all done directly from the browser url to the auth servers default login form

Hi J, here is the repo. github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF/… - unimaginably hard journey the last 6 weeks. I set the cookie in the yaml file (AUTH-SESSION), but the one in the Cookie folder (where I wanted to set it) doesn' appear, even with secure turned to false. I also get the csrf invalid error, so the filter chain fails, even on valid credentials. After that I'm hoping to move all the repos to Azure Redis (something I hoped to start on this w/e)

I think I got to the bottom of this. I was deleting cookies in the browser, but didn't actually refresh the page, so wasn't actually re-loading the login page (which is what triggers the creation of the csrf token, by the server, before the first run through the security chain). So that is why I was seeing Load Token = null, instead causing the Csrf filer to create and then save a token. But now I get through the filter chain

@JAsgarov if you’re interested I’ve updated my Auth server to support Redis Cache and RememberMe service, but it’s not fully working (same repo link as in other post)

it would be better if you ask a new question with details relevant to the new problem

full details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78829545/spring-auth-server-cannot-persist-session-csrf-cookies-to-azure-redis
