Spring Auth Server - Cannot Persist Session + CSRF cookies to Azure Redis
I've been building a Spring Auth Server the past month or so.
It can create a Session ID and CSRF Token, so now I am starting to try and take everything out of in-memory to an external Redis Cache (Azure Redis Cache)
I'm quite new to Redis, so am learning.
No persistence to Redis
When I authenticate however, nothing gets persisted to Redis:
Namespace
It should save to my defined namespace: namespace: spring:session:in-house-auth-server (as specified in the YAML properties file - see the github repo below)
Redis Screenshot
Here is the Redis Screenshot (ignore the api gateway folder)

Github Repository
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF/auth
The key folders are:

Cookies: where I set the session cookie name (only this method works, I'm not sure why, sessionCookieConfig, the cookieSerializer function doesn’t work)
Redis folder: where I've created some Redis Classes
Repositories folder: where I have the files: RedixIndexedSessionRepository, SecurityContextRepository, SessionRegistryConfig,
RequestCache folder: where I create a custom requestCache implementation
Session folder: probably all the files in there
The 3 config files: AuthServerConfig, DefaultSecurityConfig, and TomCatServerConfig
The Yaml properties file

I really am quite stuck! Can anyone see what I’m missing or where I’ve gone wrong?
Aim
All I want to do for now is store the (i) Session ID, (ii) Security Context, (iii) CSRF Token, and (iv) Request Cache to Redis - so not over the moon requirements
Would be great if anyone could provide any help.

don't just provide link to git, paste relevant code here - relevant would be any redis related code / configs / properties as well as redis related logs if any

Thanks. I’m going through the code now. It’s a lot of code, and I don’t quite know the cause, hence the references to the relevant files above. Still debugging, to understand why it’s not working

I think it's because the HTTP events and listeners and publishers aren't working properly... but I still can't see where I've gone wrong : (

You can try starting with a minimal application from Spring Initializr and build it back up, one piece at a time. You can manually test between iterations or better still continuously run integration tests. This is one of the best ways to learn, I've found.

Thanks Steve. I will try. Was all fine, before I started adding Redis support. I'm back to working on my BFF (OAuth Client), but will revisit my Spring Auth Server after I've got that working (with Redis support too). What are integration tests? How do you run those? Are there any guides?
